# Open different pages when package install and update

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I have a piece of software that I distribute through NuGet. When it installs, it opens a web page with instructions, and works well.

Now I am planing to release a second version with some breaking changes, and I would like that if you are updating rather than installing, and different page explaining the changes is opened rather than the page that explains everything from scratch.

How may I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet would be to add a `tools\uninstall.ps1` file to your `nupkg`, and then when it runs drop some sort of breadcrumb somewhere for `tools\install.ps1` to check. Probably putting it in `%temp%` is the right idea. Or the `Glimpse` plugin puts theirs in `%appdata%`.

```
$dataDir = Join-Path $env:AppData "Glimpse"
```

If the breadcrumb is there, you can open the "upgraded" web page, and if it's missing you can open the "fresh install" web page.

Speaking of Glimpse, you might want to look at their `install.ps1` and `uninstall.ps1`--they do several neat tricks there, including requesting a release notes web page that's completely customized for the specific set of packages that you just installed or upgraded.

(If you don't have a favorite way of browsing inside NuGet packages, I highly recommend [NuGet Package Explorer](http://nuget.codeplex.com/releases/view/59864).)

Comment: The problem is that I cannot alter the packages that are already installed.

Comment: I see. I can't really think of a way to do it in that case.

Comment: Thanks anyway. What a pity something like that does not exist.